# Does pointing out XY problems help poorly-researched questions to the frustration of well-researched questions?

Tags: discussion, xy-problem

I find that when asking how to do X I spend a lot of time defending why I'm not doing Y. The more research I've put into the question, the harder I have to defend, because the more likely it is that I'm doing X because I've been backed into a corner -- after all, if X were easy, I would have found my answer already and wouldn't be coming to StackOverflow. And while I appreciate the earnest flood of answers saying "do Y not X", it does mean that the person who could actually tell me how to do X is a little less likely to look at the question, thinking it has already been dealt with by many answers.

On the other hand, if the only reason I'm asking how to do X is because it's the first idea that popped into my mind and I never bothered to figure out if it's the best, then sure, tell me I should actually be doing Y, it will be very useful.

Are we making it more annoying to ask real last-resort questions about baffling challenges?

Comment: One of the benefits of interacting with others is that they find holes in your thinking.  One of the costs of interacting with others is that they become convinced they have found a hole in your thinking.

Comment: This is *very* simple to deal with, just add a line of text in your question that states that you cannot use Y.  Easy peasy, nobody will hassle you about it.  If you know that Y is the correct solution but you can't get it going then maybe you asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 8):

**I can't tell the difference between the two.**  Not without context, anyway.

I don't mean to offend or ruffle you, but given any arbitrary question at any arbitrary moment while I'm on Stack Overflow, I don't know if it's this person's final, long-shot one-in-a-million attempt at a problem, or if this is something that they're *thinking* might work.

The real problem is, unless you actually provide your defense, I'm going to assume the latter.  The reason for this is simple:  we might be able to understand your problem as you're **describing** it, but not necessarily as you **understand** it.

Take, for instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28006912/1079354).  I provided an answer to it earlier (it was, in my mind, a syntax thing), but after I typed it out, I wondered why they would want to do that in the first place.  It has the smell of an XY problem all over it, but the syntactic answer was what they were looking for.  I understood the problem as they were describing it (how do I initialize a two-dimensional array of `ArrayList<int>`?), but not as they **understood** it (they believed a 2D array would be their data structure of choice).

Providing context like this should be part of the question anyway; including why you haven't taken approach Y is going to give the answerers much needed context into why those answers aren't helpful to you.

Otherwise, you may get a whole bunch of people who only see one side of the issue, and it's really not their fault that the answer you were seeking was only half-complete or "just do Y".

Comment: But are you basically saying that since you can't tell whether I'm being good or bad, you're going to do something that would punish me if I'm good and reward me if I'm bad? That is an excellent point about context, though -- perhaps I should be punished for not providing context, since it would be helpful to someone later reading the answer with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've often considered that possibility that while newbies may not ask well posed questions, those used to doing their own research and solving their own problems often may not ask questions which are a wonderfully natural fit for usual flow of the site either.

It's almost tempting to wonder if there's an intermediate role / "style" of participation where some real effort and attention is given to research and presenting necessary information, but there's also a degree of (at least momentary) "I give up" in the act of posting, which leaves a problem in a state readily answerable to someone with a different perspective, expertise, or the simple luck to spot the oversight first.  In the real world, these are the walk to the water cooler moments.

If your instinct is to do heavy research and run down possibilities to exhaustion before asking, it may be that most of the useful answers you will gain from the site won't be from your own questions, but from ideas prompted by reading existing ones on similar topics and letting those thoughts percolate through your mind overnight. If you've really exhausted the existing post knowledge here before doing that, it's quite possible that there just aren't many users in a position to add something helpful which you are not already aware of; or at least not among those logged on and browsing at any given hour.

But that doesn't mean you shouldn't ask - once you wade through the background noise of those who think your reasons for rejecting an alternative are insufficient, you might luckily or eventually get helpful input from someone who either has an idea you haven't considered yet, or manages to make a convincing argument for why something you rejected actually can work well.

Answer (score -4):

Absolutely. Nothing pisses me off more than when I ask about *Y* and then for some unfathomable reason people propose *X*, a useless non-solution to a different problem, and it's *always* something trivial I would have found on my own if I was trying to solve the problem to which it applies.

Nothing pisses me off more than that *except for one thing:* When I Google for "How do you *Y*" and end up at the Stack Overflow question "How do you *Y*," and *all the answers are about X!* FFFFFFFFFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUU-